# Series RL AC circuit Laplace analysis

Tags: ac, power-electronics

Question: Find the complete expression for i(t) in a series RL circuit with source \$Vsin(\omega t)\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhgwUR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So to attack this I thought to bring out the ol' ant trusty Laplace tranform.

The final eqn I get is

\$ V \frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2} = (Ls+R)I(s)\$.

which becomes \$ V\omega \frac{1}{s^2+\omega^2} \frac{1}{(Ls+R)} = I(s)\$.

Can someone suggest a good method to move forward from here? I've tried fraction decomposition but I just can't move forward :(

Comment: What you could not get from the decomposition into partial fractions?

Comment: no I can't I don't really know which form to use for the decomposition

Comment: This is the case of two complex conjugate poles (no real part) and a real pole. Could you look at some material on this and report what difficulties you have encountered?

Comment: Your circuit analysis isn't wrong... but I tried the math myself and it looks like you'll have some complex numbers in your fraction decomposition.

Comment: Show your analysis so far.

Comment: Was not given time to OP for showing his analisys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take partial fractions: -

\$\dfrac{1}{(s^2+\omega^2)(s+b)}\$ becomes \$\dfrac{b-s}{(\omega^2+b^2)(s^2+\omega^2)}+\dfrac{1}{(\omega^2+b^2)(s+b)}\$

The reverse laplace of this is moderate to easy. I don't think you need me to help you with the \$\omega\$ on top or the reduction of (sL + R) to (s + b).

Comment: thanks! it was the right path, my waveform looks correct.
If you don't mind me asking, how did you make a decision to choose that expansion?

Comment: I kind of knew it would break down to an addition of the reciprocals of the two denominator terms in brackets - it usually does plus there is a great website that does numerical inverse Laplace solutions and it's easy to check your algebra by putting in values for omega and b and watching how it solves them (it takes you through all the steps). I'll post a link later but I'm at work and I don't have that link.